# Is it possible to merge 2 rows into a single row in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to merge 2 rows into a single row in SQL Server 2008?

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
| Part Number  | Site 1 | Site 2 |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|     1        | True   | False  |
|     1        | False  | True   |
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

Desired Result

```
+--------------+--------+--------+
| Part Number  | Site 1 | Site 2 |
+--------------+--------+--------+
|     1        | True   | True   |
+--------------+--------+--------+
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind you issue?

Comment: What is the LOGIC of that "merge"? e.g. how does `Part Number 2` become `Part Number 1`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The only logic I can see here is that he want to group by `[Part Number]` and select `TRUE` if present in at least one of the rows for that column, otherwise select `FALSE`. Am I right? It is still an ambiguous question.

Comment: i have users and users permission is managed by groups one user can be in multiple groups in that condition i need to merge the all groups permissions for user that is in multiple groups. Please forget about Part No field

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on what you mean by merge, but you could certainly get the data and overlay either record on top of the other using SET. While this can be done purely in SQL, you are better off building this into an application.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET
    [Site 1] = ([Site 1] | source.[Site 1]),
    [Site 2] = ([Site 2] | source.[Site 2])
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        [Part Number],
        [Site 1],
        [Site 2]
    FROM [dbp].[mytable]
    WHERE
        [Part Number] = 2
    ) source
WHERE
    [Part Number] = 1;
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable] WHERE [Part Number] = 2;
```

I Believe this should work, although I have not tested it... Also it makes the assumption that the part number is what to merge on because in the above example part number 2 seems to merge into part number 1

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code

```
create table temp
(part_number varchar(10),
site1 varchar(10),
site2 varchar(10))

insert into temp(part_number)
select part_number from temp_table 
group by part_number

update t
set site1=temp_table.site1
From temp t 
inner join temp_table
on t.part_number=temp_table.part_number
where site1='True'
update t
set site2=temp_table.site2
From temp t 
inner join temp_table
on t.part_number=temp_table.part_number
where site2='True'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx guys for your answers but i figured the easiest way to do this is

```
Select 
 CASE WHEN Sum(CONVERT(int,Site1))>0 Then 1 else 0 end as Site1,
 CASE WHEN Sum(CONVERT(int,Site2))>0 Then 1 else 0 end as Site2 
from myTable
```